# Canvas to Bitmap processed in background

Tags: android, batch-processing, android-canvas

I'm developing an app in which I have to sore drawings on a Canvas to png sequence.That has to happen every, let's say 40 milliseconds (based on 30 fps video) and then that sequence is rendered to a video.

I managed to save the Canvas to sequence but it slows down the performance when is done real-time while I'm drawing. I don't know what is slowing it down - the writing to the SD card (mine is fast enough) or the process itself (my phone is also fast enough).

So is there a way that I can store what's drawn on the Canvas at certain intervals and then generate the png-s like a background process and just display a message until the sequence is generated and written on the card.

Comment: [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java)?